# How to inflate a view returned from onCreateView()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a java class that extends a `fragment` and as you know at `onCreateView` a `layout view` will be returned to appear on the `fragment` container. Now, I want to inflate the returned

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment00, null);
        return view;
```

with another layout or views from an xml file.

***Updat***

`onCreateView()` will return a `view` that will appear on the `fragment conatiner`. Now, I want to inflate that `view` with another `xml` file. is that possible.? I hope it is clear now.

Any idea how to do that?

Code:

```
//I want to inflate "view" with another layout or views from another xml file
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment00, null);
    return view;
```

Comment: Just edit it to  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR XML FILE, null);

Comment: @SoumilDeshpande i  appreciate your suggestion but this is not the case

Comment: @SoumilDeshpande What is your case?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question

Comment: Then i didnt quite get the question.

Comment: @Sripathi as posted in the question, the view that is returned from the onCreateView should be inflated by another view or layout, is that possible.

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you want to do actually?

Comment: @pskink please see the question again. i edited it

Comment: Just change R.layout.frgment00 to another one. is it what you need?

Comment: I think you must have to define the layouts of the other fragments and add more container-views to the *container* activity (with their respective ids) and then inflate every layout and add them to their corresponding container-views.

Comment: @AlphaCoder it still doesn't explain what you want to achieve,  maybe use simple example?

Comment: @AlphaCoder So you want to inflate a layout inside a view, filled with a previously inflated layout? Why? I don't think that's possible unless you want to insert that view inside a `ContainerView` inside the first inflated view. Isn't it better to replace the fragment with a new one when data has changed as orret3 states in his answer?

Comment: @arielnmz ok, let's say i want to add some views"button, textviews,..etc" to the that view onCreateView() methods reurns. is it clear? sorry for inconvenience

Comment: If you define such views inside the XML they're inflated along with the root view. I.e. Everything that is defined inside the XML is inflated when the on create view method is called.

Comment: @AlphaCoder Or are you trying to **add** views to the ones that are originally defined inside the XML?

Answer (score 0):

Add A ViewGroup like LinerLayout/Relative  layout in the fragment00.xml with id container then at runtime you can try something like

```
View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_view,null);
LinearLayout container = getView().findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(newView,newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: My answer remain the same, just remember layout inflation is nothing but creating view heirarchy from xml. once a view is created u can't inflate the same view again but you can always add/replace/remove views to a container/viewgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a fragment, it can be swapped in or out multiple times, but in doing so the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods will be called again and thus the view will essentially be reset. if you want to go back to a fragment after instantiating it and using a FragmentTransaction to show it simply add it to the backstack when replacing like so:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentframe, myfrag)
    .addToBackstack(null)
    .commit();
```

Now you can go back to the fragment without reinstantiating it using the FragmentManager like so:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack().commit();
```

And you can manipulate it once again.

otherwise i don't see any way inflating a fragment a second time without going through the lifecycle of a fragment.